# Angular - Is .finally() Called At the End of Every Path in a Chained Promise Decision Tree?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following chained sequence of promises:

```
$scope.promisesInProgress = true
myService.myFirstPromise(id)
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.firstResponse = data;
        return myService.mySecondPromise(id);
    })
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.secondResponse = data;
    })
    .finally(function(){
        $scope.promisesInProgress = false;
    });
```

Is the `finally()` callback function being called at the very end no matter what the success / failure of the previous two promises are?

For example, if `myFirstPromise()` returned a 400 response, `mySecondPromise()` will never be called - but I assume the `finally()` block would still be thrown?  The same should be true if `mySecondPromise()` returns a 400 (and `$scope.secondResponse` is never set) and if both promises return 200s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a Jasmine test to see whether the `finally()` block is called on each function execution no matter what the chained promises returned.

```
describe('myController Test Suite', function(){

    var q, scope, deferred, myService;

    // Initialize the Pointivo module
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('myApp');
    });

    // Mock out fake service
    beforeEach(function(){
        myService = {
            myFirstPromise: function(){
                deferred = q.defer();
                // TEST ME
                deferred.resolve('first promise response');
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            mySecondPromise: function(){
                deferred = q.defer();
                // TEST ME
                deferred.resolve('second promise response');
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            myThirdPromise: function(){
                deferred = q.defer();
                // TEST ME
                deferred.resolve('third promise response');
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
        spyOn(myService, 'myFirstPromise').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(myService, 'mySecondPromise').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(myService, 'myThirdPromise').and.callThrough();
    });

    // Assign controller scope and service references
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;
        $controller('myController', {
            $scope: scope,
            myService: myService
        });
    }));

    describe('finally test', function(){
        it('should always hit the finally statement', function(){
                scope.finallyStatementFlag = false;
            scope.test();
            scope.$apply();
            expect(scope.finallyStatementFlag).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });

});
```

The above rests on the assumption that the controller looks like:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, myService){

    $scope.finallyStatementFlag = false;

    $scope.test = function(){
        myService.myFirstPromise()
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                return myService.mySecondPromise()
            })
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                return myService.myThirdPromise();
            })
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })
            .finally(function(){
                console.log('finally statement');
                $scope.finallyStatementFlag = true;
            });
    }

});
```

The above will pass even if you change any or all of the `deferred.resolve()` to `deferred.reject()` inside of the `beforeEach()` callback where we define `myService`.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2bo511uo/18/)

Answer (score 3):

Angular 1.x `$q` service inspired by Kris Kowal's Q, based on [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> finally(callback, notifyCallback) – allows you to observe either the fulfillment or rejection of a promise, but to do so without modifying the final value. This is useful to release resources or do some clean-up that needs to be done whether the promise was rejected or resolved. See the full specification for more information.

so yes, no matter `myFirstPromise` resolved or rejected, the `finally()` block would always be called

UPDATED,

to be noticed, the `finally()` block of `myFirstPromise` would be called before `mySecondPromise` resolved(or rejected), because `myFirstPromise` and `mySecondPromise` are different promise instance, and `mySecondPromise` promise instance created after `myFirstPromise` resolved